# MySQL create event scheduler with two queries

Tags: php, mysql

I need a little support with MySQL queries.
So this is how my application works and after that i will explain what i want to do in backend.

In application users can create events(something like facebook has) and automatically with those events, two groups are being created too. After that users can join these events and join these two groups in event. Now these events has expiration date, so if users don't filled up these groups on time, event will be automatically canceled.

So i need to schedule event in mysql and check if groups in event are filled up with minimum number of users and this event should be triggered every one minute.

This is how my tables looks:

```
event
- id
- group_one_id (Foreign key)
- group_two_id (Foreign key)

groups
- id

user_groups
- id
- user_id
- group_id
```

So this is some conditions my query should have:

Count of users in two groups should be greater than 10

```
    CREATE EVENT myevent
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 50 SECOND
DO
UPDATE events
SET status = 2 // event is canceled
WHERE .. // here i need help
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query:**

```
UPDATE eventtab e
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT group_id, count(user_id) AS group_one_users_count 
        FROM user_groups 
            GROUP BY group_id
    ) temp1
    ON e.group_one_id = temp1.group_id
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT group_id, count(user_id) AS group_two_users_count 
        FROM user_groups 
            GROUP BY group_id
    ) temp2
    ON e.group_two_id = temp2.group_id
SET event_status = 2
WHERE 
    IFNULL(group_one_users_count, 0) < 10
 OR IFNULL(group_two_users_count, 0) < 10;
```

**Explanation:**

To be able to count the number of participants in a group, an aggregation query would need to be run on `user_groups`. Now since there are **two** `group_id`s in the `eventtab` (within the same table), two separate aggregation queries would be required. This is what the two `LEFT JOIN`s are there for.

It may also be possible that there aren't any users for a certain `group_id` (i.e. no matching records) in `user_groups` table. This means that the `LEFT JOIN` with the `group_id` (i.e. `group_one_id` or `group_two_id`) FROM `eventtab` would return `NULL` values when the `JOIN` is in effect. The query should therefore consider these `NULL` values as `0` instead to spot the candidate `group_id`s in the `eventtab` for which `event_status` should be set to `2`.

**Assumption:**

An assumption made here is that the *event would be called off if the count of number of users in either of the groups associated with the event is less than 10*. If the combined count was supposed to be considered then the query would only need a minor tweak as follows:

```
WHERE 
    ( IFNULL(group_one_users_count, 0) 
      + 
      IFNULL(group_two_users_count, 0) 
    ) < 10
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/IRWAO53740)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Much much helped me. Really detail explanation. Thanks buddy!